# return value from python-shell as response

Tags: python, json, node.js, angular, flask

I'm using python shell to run python on nodeJS. I need to return python shell out put as the response. but when i try to send the response it shows an error

```
Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

here is my code

```
app.post('/therun', (req, res)=>{

    var pyshell = new PythonShell('hello.py');

    pyshell.on('message', function (message) {

       console.log(message); //value is correct
       res.send(message); //error here

      });

       res.send(message); //if i use here message undefined


});
```

How to slove this?

Answer (score 1):

```
    app.post('/therun', (req, res)=>{

    var pyshell = new PythonShell('hello.py');
    var test={};

    pyshell.on('message', function (message) {

       console.log(message); //value is correct
       //res.send(message); //error here
      test=message;

      });
       console.log(test);
       res.send(message); //if i use here message undefined


});
```

Can you tell me the response on your console for the value of test ?

Comment: @LVW23 can you change this line test=message; to this.test=message and let me know the log after it?
Also what is your console.log(message) giving in the output if you can share that would be a help to clarify few things

Comment: node is not the problem i wanted to have a few observations running this piece of code
 1) does your console.log(message) comes out in json format 
2)If message is being populated correctly then the response is picking it up correctly or not?
@LVW23

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending it as,

```
res.send(message); //error here
```

Can you please try sending the same with a status code given below?

```
res.status(200).json({
  "message":message
})
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the python shell (after pyshell.on()):

```
pyshell.end(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```